# Why can't I read Oracles CLOB columns via SQL-SERVER 2008 linked server?

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle-11g

I want to access data in an Oracle 11g database from SQL-Server 2008

I set up a linked server and when I execute

```
select * from [Link_server_name]..Oracle_schema.Oracle_table
```

and Oracle_table contains Number and varchar2 columns, all works as excepted.

But when the Oracle_table contains a CLOB column, I get the following error:

Der OLE DB-Anbieter 'MSDAORA' für den Verbindungsserver 'L_V407SR8T' hat die Meldung 'Unspecified error' zurückgeben.

Der OLE DB-Anbieter 'MSDAORA' für den Verbindungsserver 'L_V407SR8T' hat die Meldung 'Oracle error occurred, but error message could not be retrieved from Oracle.' zurückgeben.

Der OLE DB-Anbieter 'MSDAORA' für den Verbindungsserver 'L_V407SR8T' hat die Meldung 'Data type is not supported.' zurückgeben.

Msg 7306, Level 16, State 2, Line 1

Die '"MCCAPP"."DOGGRUPPEN"'-Tabelle vom OLE DB-Anbieter 'MSDAORA' für den Verbindungsserver 'L_V407SR8T' kann nicht geöffnet werden.

Using OPENQUERY

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([L_V407SR8T], 'Select CLOB_COLUMN from Oracle_table'  )
```

I get

Der OLE DB-Anbieter 'MSDAORA' für den Verbindungsserver 'L_V407SR8T' hat die Meldung 'Oracle error occurred, but error message could not be retrieved from Oracle.' zurückgeben.
Der OLE DB-Anbieter 'MSDAORA' für den Verbindungsserver 'L_V407SR8T' hat die Meldung 'Data type is not supported.' zurückgeben.

Please excuse German error messages.

My question: Is there any way to read CLOB columns via linked Servers?

EDIT:

- SQL Server Import and Export Wizard
  seems to depend on OLE DB too and
  sucks on the same tables
- I'm asking myself, if the problem
  depends on the character sets uses,
  but I can't change them
- As practical work around, I use some
  PowerShell scripts to get at the
  data, but

Comment: You should be able to read the CLOB if you at least can convert it first ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378813.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Download and install an Oracle 11 database client on your SQL Server 2008 machine.

Set up a linked server using an Oracle OLE DB provider (OraOLEDB.Oracle).

Make sure "Allow InProcess" is enabled in Provider options.

The Oracle 11 OLE DB client supports CLOBs.

Answer (score 2):

A comment to an answer SO question
[How to read a CLOB column in Oracle using OleDb ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537613/how-to-read-a-clob-column-in-oracle-using-oledb)

contains a link to old [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244661)  post with the following statement

> Oracle 8.x-specific data types, such
>   as CLOB, BLOB, BFILE, NCHAR, NCLOB,
>   and NVARCHAR2, are not supported.

It would be nice to find some more current references.

I did some Google research and found only workarounds. I fear the data type is still not supported.

**Edit 02/05/2011**

I really do not understand why Microsoft isn't able to fix this issue. The following PowerShell Script uses OLE-DB to read a table containing a CLOB column from an Oracle database and insert the data into an existing similar table on Sql-Server using bulkCopy which is a very efficient way.

Adjust the following connection strings, query and table name to your installation:

```
# Here I use OLE-DB to read the Oracle database
$ConnectionString ="Server=ignore;User Id=myUser;Password=myPassword;Data Source=myTns;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;"

# Here I use .NET SqlClient
$SqlClientConnString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=myDestinationDB;Integrated Security=True"

$sql = "select int_col, clob_col from TABLE_WITH_CLOB"
$tableName = "COPY_OF_CLOB_TABLE"
```

The following code copies the oracle table into a sql-server table

```
$OLEDBConn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection($ConnectionString)
$OLEDBConn.open()
$readcmd = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand($sql,$OLEDBConn)
$readcmd.CommandTimeout = '300'
$da = New-Object system.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter($readcmd)
$dt = New-Object system.Data.datatable
[void]$da.fill($dt)
$OLEDBConn.close()
#Write-Output $dt


if ($dt)
{
    try
    {
        $bulkCopy = new-object ("Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy") $SqlClientConnString
        $bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = $tableName
        $bulkCopy.BatchSize = 50000
        $bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0
        $bulkCopy.WriteToServer($dt)
    }
    catch
    {
        $ex = $_.Exception
        #Write-LogMessage -Source 'Write-DataTable' -Message "$($connectionName):$ex.Message"
        Write-Error "Write-DataTable$($connectionName):$ex.Message"
        continue
    }
}
```

BTW: the code is based on Chad Millers [Really Simple Data Dictionary codeplex project](http://rsdd.codeplex.com/)

Currently using PowerShell is the only way I know to copy Data with CLOBs from Oracle to Sql-Server not using C# or any third party tools.

I didn't succeed using neither Import/Export Wizard nor linked servers.

Comment: grrrr that sucks considering it's been three point releases for ORA and at least one point release for MS since then ... AHA `No new updates are planned for future releases of these components including their support against versions later than Oracle 8i.`

Comment: _I really do not understand why Microsoft isn't able to fix this issue_? For the same reason Microsoft stopped supporting the dotnet framework Oracle client library -  "other people do it better", if I ruthlessly paraphrase their responses in the past.  No love lost between those two, I tell you.