# Moving tables to another SQL2008 database (including indexes, triggers, etc.)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, migration

I need to move a whole bunch (100+) of large (millions of rows) tables from one SQL2008 database to another.

I originally just used the Import/Export Wizard, but all the destination tables were missing primary and foreign keys, indexes, constraints, triggers, etc. (Identity columns were also converted to plain INTs, but I think I just missed a checkbox in the wizard.)

What's the right way to do this?

If this were just a couple of tables, I would go back to the source, script out the table definition (with all indexes, etc), then run the index creation portions of the script on the destination. But with so many tables, this seems impractical.

If there wasn't quite so much data, I could use the "Create Scripts..." wizard to script out the source, including data, but a 72m row script just doesn't seem like a good idea!

Comment: And it's not all the tables in the database?

Comment: @thursdaysgeek: Its *nearly* all tables, but the destination database has 100+ tables already. So just restoring from backup with a different name isn't an option. Think of this as basically "merge these two large databases together".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We actually did it using a lot of manual scripting in conjunction with the Import wizard, but this morning I found a better answer, courtesy of [Tibor Karaszi's blog article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2008/06/21/import-export-wizard-and-indexes-keys-etc.aspx).

Part of our frustration here was that the **SQL 2000** "DTS Import/Export Wizard" actually makes this almost trivially easy by selecting "Copy Objects and Data":

[image: DTS Import Wizard]

This third option is the one that contains the ability to include indexes/triggers, etc:

[image: Advanced Options]

This option was **REMOVED** from the *SQL 2005/2008* Import Wizard. Why? No idea:

[image: 2008 Import Wizard]

In 2005/2008, you apparently have to *manually* create an SSIS package in BIDS and use the [Transfer SQL Server Objects Task](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/transfer_sql_objects_task_ssis_p2.aspx), which contains all the same options that were in the 2000 wizard:

[image: SSIS Transfer SQL Server Objects Task]

Comment: Just wanted to post that I used this SSIS method for another similar task, and it worked great!

Answer (score 14):

Scripting out the tables, then using SSIS to transfer the data would be the most reliable and effective way of moving the data to the new database.

Answer (score 8):

I'd consider scripting the table out, or use a compare tools (eg Red Gate) to generate the tables in the target database. Without indexes or constraints yet.

Then I'd consider restoring the database with a different name on the same server and doing

```
 INSERT newdb.dbo.newtable SELECT * FROM olddb.dbo.oldtable
```

.. for each table, with SET IDENTITY INSERT ON if requirede

Then I'd add indexes and constraints after loading data.

It depends on your comfort level with SSIS (mrdenny's answer) or if you prefer raw SQL.

Answer (score 6):

I'd add to Mr Denny's answer: Script out the tables schema then use BCP to move the data.
If you're not familiar with SSIS, then using BCP and batches should be easy to do.
For millions of rows nothing beats BCP (bulk insert) :).

Answer (score 4):

I'm the one who is completely uncomfortable with SSIS.

When the source tables have no identity columns

1. create a empty database at the target server
2. create a linked server to the source server on the target server
3. run the script below on the source database to generate select * into ... statements
4. run the generated script from the target database
5. script primary keys, indexes, triggers, functions and procedures from source database
6. create these objects by the generated script

Now the T-SQL to generate the Select * into ... statements

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

declare @name sysname
declare @sql varchar(255)

declare db_cursor cursor for
select name from sys.tables order by 1
open db_cursor

fetch next from db_cursor into @name
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    Set @sql = 'select * into [' + @name + '] from [linked_server].[source_db].[dbo].[' + @name + '];'
    print @sql

    fetch next from db_cursor into @name
end

close db_cursor
deallocate db_cursor
```

This generates a line for each table to copy like

```
select * into [Table1] from [linked_server].[source_db].[dbo].[Table1];
```

In case that the tables contain identity columns, I script the tables including identity property and primary keys.

I do not use insert into ... select ... using a linked server in this case, as this is no bulk technique. I'm  working on some PowerShell scripts similar to [this SO question[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968548/load-dataset-to-sql-script-in-powershell), but I'm still working on error handling. Really big tables can cause out of memory errors, as a whole table is loaded into memory, before it is send via SQLBulkCopy to the database.

Recreation of indexes etc. is similar to the case above. This time I can skip the recreation of the primary keys.

Comment: In case the tables contain identity columns, you can do like in this [question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/916/how-to-copy-a-table-ignoring-the-identity-property-with-select-into). It will save you some manual work. I still prefer bulk insert batches/SSIS, linked server may not be a good solution over a wide network.

Comment: @Marian Please take a look at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/297/why-cant-i-read-oracles-clob-columns-via-sql-server-2008-linked-server if you want to promote SSIS. I didn't try SSIS, but Import Export Wizard failed too (besides linked server).

Comment: I would've helped with pleasure, but I don't have any Oracle box available to me. Anyway, from what I've managed to read, there are no providers that will support Oracle CLOB..

Comment: I am with you on this - I do migrate data sometimes, but never use SSIS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use comparison tools that compare database schemas and data and first synchronize a **blank** database schema with the original db, to create all the tables.

Then, synchronize the data from the original database with the new one (all tables are there, but they are all empty) to insert the records into the tables

I use [ApexSQL Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.aspx) and [ApexSQL Data Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_datadiff.aspx) for this, but there are other similar tools.

The good thing about this process is that you don't have to actually synchronize the databases using the tool, as this can be quite painful for millions of rows.

You can just **create an INSERT INTO SQL script** (don't be surprised if it's several gigs) and execute it.

As so large scripts cannot even be opened in SQL Server Management Studio, I use [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) or [osql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214012%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As @mrdenny mentioned -

1. script out tables first with all Indexes, FK's, etc and create blank tables in the destination database.

Instead of using SSIS, use BCP to insert data

1. bcp out the data using below script. set SSMS in Text Mode and copy the output generated by below script in a bat file.

   ```
   -- save below output in a bat file by executing below in SSMS in TEXT mode

   -- clean up: create a bat file with this command --> del D:\BCP\*.dat 

   select '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe" ' /* path to BCP.exe */
       +  QUOTENAME(DB_NAME())+ '.' /* Current Database */
       +  QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID))+'.'            
       +  QUOTENAME(name)  
       +  ' out D:\BCP\'  /* Path where BCP out files will be stored */
       +  REPLACE(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),' ','') + '_' 
       +  REPLACE(name,' ','') 
       + '.dat -T -E -SServerName\Instance -n' /* ServerName, -E will take care of Identity, -n is for Native Format */
   from sys.tables
   where is_ms_shipped = 0 and name <> 'sysdiagrams'                       /* sysdiagrams is classified my MS as UserTable and we dont want it */
   /*and schema_name(schema_id) <> 'unwantedschema'    */                             /* Optional to exclude any schema  */
   order by schema_name(schema_id)
   ```
2. Run the bat file that will generate the .dat files in the folder that you have specified.
3. Run below script on the

   ```
   --- Execute this on the destination server.database from SSMS.

   --- Make sure the change the @Destdbname and the bcp out path as per your environment.

   declare @Destdbname sysname
   set @Destdbname = 'destinationDB' /* Destination Database Name where you want to Bulk Insert in */
   select 'BULK INSERT ' 
   /*Remember Tables must be present on destination database */ 
   + QUOTENAME(@Destdbname) + '.' 
   + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID)) 
   + '.' + QUOTENAME(name) 
   + ' from ''D:\BCP\' /* Change here for bcp out path */ 
   + REPLACE(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id), ' ', '') + '_' + REPLACE(name, ' ', '') 
   + '.dat'' with ( KEEPIDENTITY, DATAFILETYPE = ''native'', TABLOCK )' 
   + char(10) 
   + 'print ''Bulk insert for ' + REPLACE(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id), ' ', '') + '_' + REPLACE(name, ' ', '') + ' is done... ''' 
   + char(10) + 'go'
      from sys.tables
      where is_ms_shipped = 0
   and name <> 'sysdiagrams' /* sysdiagrams is classified my MS as UserTable and we dont want it */
   and schema_name(schema_id) <> 'unwantedschema' /* Optional to exclude any schema */
       order by schema_name(schema_id)
   ```
4. Run the output using SSMS to insert data back in the tables.

This is very fast bcp method as it uses Native mode.